# Rewrite rule changes order of expression

Tags: calc

Let's say I have a rewrite rule

L(a + b) := L(a) + L(b)

when we apply this rule to rewrite L(x+y) the result is

L(y) + L(x)

but I would like it to give

L(x) + L(y),

i.e. to keep the same order of the original expression (if possible).